# What would cause a mysqli statement to use 4GB of memory when the returned data is less than 10k?

Tags: php, apache, unix, memory, mysqli

Searched high and low, and can't find the answer to this.. other than "bump up your PHP memory usage limit", which makes no sense in this case.  So here goes..

Here is a bit of code (edited to show code above what I previously put here):

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', "XXXXXX");
define('DB_USER', "XXXXXX");
define('DB_PASS', "XXXXXX");
define('DB_SERVER', "cloud1.XXXXXXXX.com");

// Create connection info
global $dbLink;
$dbLink= mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) ;

/*------------------------- Retreiving columns names --------------*/

$event_stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($dbLink,"select form_id,display_meta from wp_rg_form_meta order by form_id asc");
mysqli_stmt_execute($event_stmt1);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($event_stmt1, $id, $display_meta);
```

There are literally 20 rows in this database table.  Here is what is returned from those 20 rows (which is correct data, by the way):

[image]

When I first ran this code,  this error occured:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)
```

This occurred on the "mysqli_stmt_bind_result..." line.

What in the WORLD would cause this to ask for more than 4GBs of memory??  And any idea how to get rid of this?

ADDED TO SHOW "DESCRIBE" OF TABLE:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a PHP bug.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386)

Your options, in order of preference, are:

- Upgrade your server to PHP 5.4 or later. PHP 5.4 uses a different MySQL interface library (mysqlnd) which is not affected by this bug.
- Call `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` before `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`, so that PHP will load the entire result set into memory. However, note that this will require that all data returned by the query to be loaded into memory at once, which may cause problems for large result sets.
- Change the type of that column from `LONGTEXT` to a shorter type. For instance, `MEDIUMTEXT` has a maximum size of 16 MB, rather than 4 GB, so it will have less of an impact on memory usage.

Comment: So I'm going to give you credit for this answer since after doing some research we found the following:  Changing the field to "mediumtext" completely solved the problem.  And.. I tend to believe that this would be no issue on a 5.4 PHP version - as you mention.  Thanks Duskwuff.

Comment: As a side note... this field is from the "Gravity Forms" plugin for Wordpress.  I'm also going to report this issue to them, for legacy system's sake.